# How to check if input symbol is a arithmetic operators C++?

Tags: c++

I'm new in c++ and I started to learn it and I have to detect if an input symbol from keyboard is an arithmetic operators or not. Can anyone help me with simple code ?

Comment: Break it into smaller problems. Can you read a symbol from input at all? Can you check if a symbol is equal to `'+'`? Can you check if a symbol is equal to any of two particular values? Take each step in turn and then combine them into what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function.

```
bool isArithemitcOperator(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case '+': return true; break;
    case '-': return true; break;
    case '*': return true; break;
    case '/': return true; break;
    default: return false; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say `break` is redundant with `return`. Some compilers might report 'unreachable code' warnings.